# Can we capture remote screen (like screen recorder) using Putty?

Tags: c#, linux, ssh, remote-access, putty

I would like to access the remote-pc screen using putty. I am using putty on windows and would like to access Linux machine screen using windows. Is it possible to access?

Comment: you would probably better off using remote-desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to desktop UI use VNC client / server program.

Putty only grant access via ssh that is console view.